# how to create resuable textfield with validator in flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, textfield

I am creating a login form which has username and password field, i want to add validation when user skip any field. I have created this reusable textfield.

```
class RoundedInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final FormFieldValidator validate;
  const RoundedInputField({Key key, this.hintText,
    this.onChanged,
   this.controller,this.validate,
 
  })
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFieldContainer(
      child: TextFormField(
        onChanged: onChanged,            
        controller: TextEditingController(),
        validator: validate,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and calling it like this

```
 RoundedInputField(hintText: "Username",icon: Icons.email,fontsize: 20,
                controller: TextEditingController(text: user.username),
                onChanged: (value){
                  user.username=value;
                },
                validate: (value){
                  if(value.isEmpty){
                    return "This field is required";
                  }
                },
                ),
```

but validator property is not working properly, here it is.

[image]

please help if anyone know how to fix it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been using TextFormField in a reusable way like this , it has served me for all the purposes i needed , i think it works for your case too

```
class BoxTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final FormFieldValidator<String> validator;
  final bool obsecure;
  final bool readOnly;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final VoidCallback onEditingCompleted;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final bool isMulti;
  final bool autofocus;
  final bool enabled;
  final String errorText;
  final String label;
  final Widget suffix;
  final Widget prefix;

  BoxTextField(
      {Key key,
      this.controller,
      this.validator,
      this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
      this.obsecure = false,
      this.onTap,
      this.isMulti = false,
      this.readOnly = false,
      this.autofocus = false,
      this.errorText,
      @required this.label,
      this.suffix,
      this.prefix,
      this.enabled = true,
      this.onEditingCompleted,
      this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
      child: TextFormField(
          onChanged: onChanged,
          onEditingComplete: onEditingCompleted,
          autofocus: autofocus,
          minLines: isMulti ? 4 : 1,
          maxLines: isMulti ? null : 1,
          onTap: onTap,
          enabled: enabled,
          readOnly: readOnly,
          obscureText: obsecure,
          keyboardType: keyboardType,
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorText: errorText,
            prefixIcon: prefix,
            suffixIcon: suffix,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: lableFontSize()),
            labelText: label,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 15),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 20),
            enabledBorder: textFieldfocused(),
            border: textFieldfocused(),
            focusedBorder: textFieldfocused(),
            errorBorder: errorrTextFieldBorder(),
            focusedErrorBorder: errorrTextFieldBorder(),
          ),
          validator: validator),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Usage

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  TextEditingController _emailPhone = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _password = new TextEditingController();

  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  String loginError;
  bool loggingIn = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    BoxTextField(
                      validator: (str) {
                        if (str.isEmpty) {
                          return tr('common.required');
                        }

                        return null;
                      },
                      controller: _emailPhone,
                      label: tr('login.username'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    BoxTextField(
                      label: tr('login.password'),
                      controller: _password,
                      obsecure: true,
                      validator: (str) {
                        if (str.isEmpty) {
                          return tr('common.required');
                        }

                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
         Center(
                        child: BoxButton(
                      loading: loggingIn,
                      lable: tr('login.btn'),
                      onPressed: () {
                          
                            },
                    )),
                  ],
                )),
          )
        ]))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can u please edit ur code, with how to call this

Comment: give me a minute

Comment: i have edited according to your request , i think it explains it

Comment: what is str ? is it _controller.text?

Answer (score 3):

Replace your code and try this:

```
RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Username",
              icon: Icons.email,
              fontsize: 20,
              controller: TextEditingController(text: user.username),
              onChanged: (value) {
                user.username = value;
              },
              validate: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return "This field is required";
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
```

Comment: is "TextFieldContainer" is your custom widget?

Comment: Add return null to else block... wait rewriting the code

Comment: it's correctly formatted, but where this  "This field is required" will display?

Comment: Actually, we need to anyhow return something from the function. So whenever the field is filled, in that condition we need to return null. But if field is not filled then only we will return "This field is required".

Comment: i did that, but when i run the code and leave the textfield empty, then this msg "This field is required" should print below that textfield